# Comparing specific rows per a group of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table that I want to monitor for differences in counts based on a group of records.

In the table below records are grouped by the Source name (Customer, Product, Service), I want to check when the Total_Count of the ‘staging_’ and ‘delta_’ Entity columns is different.

For example for the Source - Customer, the Total_Count for the Entity staging_Customer and delta_Customer is the same so the output should return the difference 755 - 755 = 0, the same output should be there for the Source - Service 340 - 340 = 0.

However, for the Source - Product the staging_Product Total_Count and the delta_Product Total_Count are not the same so the output query should return the difference, so 240 - 0 = 240.

Each source always has 4 Entity records and the naming convention is always the same (hdp_[Source]*sql, staging*[Source], delta_[Source], final_[Source]).

| Run_Date | Source | Process | Entity | Total_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20180101 | Customer | tr_Customer_Data | hdp_Customer_sql | 1500 |
| 20180101 | Customer | tr_Customer_Data | staging_Customer | 755 |
| 20180101 | Customer | tr_Customer_Data | delta_Customer | 755 |
| 20180101 | Customer | tr_Customer_Data | final_Customer | 755 |
| 20180101 | Product | tr_Product_Data | hdp_Product_sql | 570 |
| 20180101 | Product | tr_Product_Data | staging_Product | 240 |
| 20180101 | Product | tr_Product_Data | delta_Product | 0 |
| 20180101 | Product | tr_Product_Data | final_Product | 0 |
| 20180101 | Service | tr_Service_Data | hdp_Service_sql | 2300 |
| 20180101 | Service | tr_Service_Data | staging_Service | 340 |
| 20180101 | Service | tr_Service_Data | delta_Service | 340 |
| 20180101 | Service | tr_Service_Data | final_Service | 340 |

Expected output:

| Run_Date | Source | Differences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20180101 | Customer | 0 |
| 20180101 | Customer | 240 |
| 20180101 | Customer | 0 |

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please also include your current query and explain exactly where you are having trouble

Comment: @Larnu changed the images to text

Comment: @Stu current query is a basic group by which isn't very useful, I am having trouble picking out the rows where the entity is staging_ and delta_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I filtered out unnecessary information using a `where` clause, and then I used `lag` to compare total_count of the entities in question.

```
select Run_Date
      ,Source
      ,Differences
from 
       (select Run_Date
              ,Source
              ,abs(Total_Count-lag(Total_Count) over(partition by source order by Entity)) as Differences
              ,row_number() over(partition by source order by Entity desc)                 as rn
        from t
        where Entity like '%staging%' or  
              Entity like '%Delta%'   
       ) t
where rn = 1
```

| Run_Date | Source | Differences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20180101 | Customer | 0 |
| 20180101 | Product | 240 |
| 20180101 | Service | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80d8b9b0989e9da52b3ba1513cdee87e&hide=1)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like for your sample data the following should provide your desired result:

```
select distinct run_date, Source, 
    First_Value(total_count) over(partition by source order by entity desc) 
    - First_Value(total_count) over(partition by source order by entity) Differences
from t
where entity like 'delta%' or entity like 'staging%';
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8497583cc17f6a49854500d3d7858e09)

Comment: I like yours better than mine. I wasn't familiar with First_Value